# bootstrap grid styles intended for extra small also works for medium screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to apply some css targeting only the XS screens, but it is being applied for medium screen as well.

[image]

See the style defined clearly for .col-xs, but I am viewing it in full screen on a desktop and it renders xs specific styles.

Am I doing something wrong here or missing any snippet from bootstrap?

Thanks,

Comment: You are selecting elements based on whether they have the class `col-xs-12` - and your element does have that class, at *any* viewport width. You of course need to wrap your selectors in the appropriate media queries, if you want them to work only on certain screen sizes.

Comment: hmm...so we can't  specify styles only form the elements spanning inside col-xs-12.. I thought we could do away with media queries when we use bootstrap...

Comment: _“so we can't specify styles only form the elements spanning inside col-xs-12”_ – no, because your element _always_ has this class. That class doesn’t magically disappear at a certain screen width. That those elements _behave_ differently at different screen sizes, is due to the fact that Bootstrap itself uses media queries to format elements with those classes differently at different screen sizes. So that will work “automatically” on the elements that have the class `col-xs-12` themselves. […]

Comment: […] But here you are simply using that class as part of a selector path to target different elements - and for the resulting rule you need to write your own media queries.

Comment: oh thanks :) .. "That class doesn’t magically disappear at a certain screen width. " -- always thought bootstrap does this through its javascript...

Answer (score 3):

The CSS classes on elements are *always* applied unless there is a media query.

In the case of [Bootstrap specific media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) this would be..

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

   .prop-image {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you're using column in bootstrap right now is saying at a md width span 4 columns and at a xs width span the entire page. It does nothing to hide content.

If you want an easy way to hide and only show the content at xs screen width you need media queries, or another option is to use Bootstraps built in responsive utility class of

.visible-xs-*.

This will only show the containing element at xs.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes